# How to use PHP to return only the first part of my file name, not the extension, ".php"

Tags: php

I am trying to set the ID of the `<body>` tag to be the name of the current page...

```
<body id="<?= basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>">
```

Why is this returning:

```
<body id="wildlife.php">
```

?

I want just the word "wildlife."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to add the extension suffix to strip off, Try this

```
<body id="<?= basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.php')?>">
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way :

```
basename($PHP_SELF,".php");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
if (preg_match('#([^/]+)\.\w+$#', 'http://www.mysite.com/home.php', $matches))
    $basename = $matches[1];
```